# woocommerce update product with variables in url

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to update products with the variables in the url e.g.

```
http://www.demo.demo/example/test.php?$id=4944&$price=1&$quantity=33&$stockStatus=instock
```

My php file is like this

```
<?php

error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 'On' );
require_once( '../wp-load.php' );

function update_product_stock($id, $quantity, $price, $stockStatus) {
   $wc_product = new WC_Product($id);
   $wc_product->set_stock($quantity);
   $wc_product->set_price($price);
   $wc_product->set_stock_status($stockStatus);
   return true;
}

update_product_stock($_GET['$id'], $_GET['$quantity'], $_GET['$price'], $_GET['$stockStatus']);
print_r("Fin");

?>
```

My problem is that the price does not get updated
can anyone help?

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered using the [API](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#update-a-product)?

Comment: started of trying with the API and couldn't get anything to update, there is not enough documentation

Answer (score 1):

Ok for anyone else that is interested, if you want to update products price and stock from variables in URL e.g.

```
http://localhost/example/test.php?$id=4944&$quantity=99&$price=999&$stockStatus=instock
```

php code:

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 'On' );
require_once( '../wp-load.php' );



function update_product_stock($id, $quantity, $stockStatus) {
//$productInfo = returnWC_API()->get_product($id)->{"product"};
$wc_product = new WC_Product($id);
$wc_product->set_stock($quantity);
$wc_product->set_price($price);
update_post_meta( $id, '_regular_price', $_GET['$price'] );
$wc_product->set_stock_status($stockStatus);
return true;
}

update_product_stock($_GET['$id'], $_GET['$quantity'], $_GET['$stockStatus']);
print_r("Fin");
?>
```